# Track progress of a SQL Server Job on an ASP.NET page

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, ssis

I have an ASP.net page that uploads an Excel files, then executes a SQL Server Job that in turn launch a SSIS package to import it.
I can check if the Job started or failed to start, but how to track its progress or, al least, know if it has finished running successfully and display the outcome on the ASP.net page itsels?

My code is the following:

```
 protected void ProcessData(int num)
    {
        SqlConnection jobConnection;
        SqlCommand jobCommand;
        SqlParameter jobReturnValue;
        SqlParameter jobParameter;
        int jobResult;

        //SSIS CONNECTION
        jobConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\XX_XXX;Initial Catalog=msdb;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        jobCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_start_job", jobConnection);
        jobCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        jobReturnValue = new SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
        jobReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        jobCommand.Parameters.Add(jobReturnValue);

        jobParameter = new SqlParameter("@job_name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        jobParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        jobCommand.Parameters.Add(jobParameter);
        jobParameter.Value = "RunXXX_Package0" + num;

        jobConnection.Open();
        jobCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        jobResult = (Int32)jobCommand.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
        switch (jobResult)
        {
            case 0:
                Label2.Text = "SQL Server Agent job, RunXXX_Package0" + num + " started successfully.";
                break;
            default:
                Label2.Text = "SQL Server Agent job, RunXXX_Package0" + num + "  failed to start.";
                break;
        }
        jobConnection.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the SSIS package write it's progress to an execution log (or history) table (which you would have to design).

Then simply have your ASP page read the table.

Comment: yeah, that was an option I was considering, I was wodnering it SSIS has some kind of additional API/Callback function to notify the caller of it's progress or at least outcome...

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: me too. The "sp_start_job" procedure only returns 0 or 1 wheter the Job started or failed

Comment: If you are using the Project Deployment model, you might be able to have the asp page query some table in SSISDB to see progress.

Comment: I can implement Logging into a table in SSIS, then I can simply query the dbo.sysssislog table looking for the right messages (at least the "PackageEnd" event...)

Answer (score 0):

You could get poll `[sp_help_job][1]` to get the info:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @Job_name = 'YourJobName'
```

And than check **execution_status**

```
0 - Returns only those jobs that are not idle or suspended.
1 - Executing.
2 - Waiting for thread.
3 - Between retries.
4 - Idle.
5 - Suspended.
7 - Performing completion actions.
```

and **last_run_outcome**

```
0 = Failed
1 = Succeeded
3 = Canceled
5 = Unknown
```